# How can I install clang-format version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final) on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, clang-format

The current clang-format that I have is version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1 and I'm having a difficult time downgrading to version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2

I tried the following:
`sudo apt-get install clang-format-6` 
output:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 2803347 (apt)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Comment: 1. The system seems to run `apt update` in background. Just wait a few minutes and try again. 2. You might run `apt` in another terminal window, finish it.

Comment: Thank you. I killed the process and now I get the following:
`sudo apt-get install -y clang-format-6.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package clang-format-6.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'clang-format-6.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'clang-format-6.0'
`

Comment: It's true, it doesn't have clang-format-6 https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clang-format&searchon=names&suite=jammy&section=all

Comment: So I can't run  'clang-format-6.0' on  Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: You can install the oldest official clang-format-11.